# gtkmm Gtk::Layout negative child position not setting its absolute position

Tags: infinite-scroll, gtkmm

The description of `Gtk::Layout` says

> Infinite scrollable area containing child widgets and/or custom drawing

I put a `Gtk::Layout` inside a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow`, gave the `Gtk::Layout` a size of 400x400 and then placed a `Gtk::Button` at (450, 450), but the scrollbars only appeared until the scrolled window was resized to 400x400, *not* (450+button-width x 450+button-height). So I had to move the bottom-right corner of the layout by connecting a handler to button's `signal_size_allocate()` signal and manually call `Gtk::Layout::set_size()` function to resize it up to button's boundary. Now the scrolled window shows scrollbars to reach the button. Up to this everything was OK.

```
class LayoutWindowTest : public ApplicationWindow {
    ScrolledWindow sw;
    Layout l;
    Button b;
public:
    LayoutWindowTest()
    : l(), b("test") {
        set_title("layout test");
        set_size_request(400, 400);
        sw.set_hadjustment(l.get_hadjustment());
        sw.set_vadjustment(l.get_vadjustment());
        l.set_size(400, 400);
        sw.add(l);
        add(sw);
        // b.get_allocation() won't work because button has not been allocated a
        // size yet
        b.signal_size_allocate().connect(
        [this](Allocation& btn_sz) {
            l.set_size(btn_sz.get_x() + btn_sz.get_width(),
                       btn_sz.get_y() + btn_sz.get_height());
        });
        l.put(b, 450, 450);
        show_all_children();
    }

    virtual ~LayoutWindowTest() {}
};
```

**Initial window showing scrollbars and then scrolled to bottom-right corner to show button**

[image: initial window showing scrollbars] 
[image: scrolled to bottom-right corner to show button]

Now I need to do the same thing for the top-left corner, i.e. put the button out of visible boundary of scrolled window and then use the scrollbars to reach the button. I tried putting the button at (-10, -10), but unlike the previous case I can't set layout's top-left corner with code by resizing it, so can't move the layout's scrollbars. When I resize the scrolled window manually by its top-left corner the button moves towards top-left with it instead of staying there. How to remedy this situation?

**Initial window with button at (-10, -10) and no scrollbars, tried resizing the window by top-left handle but button moves with it**

[image: initial window with button at -10,-10] 
[image: button moves with window when resizing it]

In short, *how can I scroll in both top-left and bottom-right directions infinitely?*